# Solr facet with sub facets

Tags: solr, grouping, facet

I'm trying to find a solution to make a subfacet list for some facets.

I have a clothes size on some products and they are stored in solr

"Size_both":"W30L30",
"Size_width":"W30",
"Size_length":"L30"

I wish to generate a list of subfacet for each width:

1. W30 (8)

   - L30 (3)
   - L32 (1)
   - L33 (4)
2. W32 (2)

   - L30 (1)
   - L34 (1)

etc

Anyone know how to accomplish this? I thought I could do this with group, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Facet Pivoting to achieve desired result:

[Facet Pivoting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting)

Try Below Query:

```
http://<host_name>:<port>/solr/<core_name>/select?q=*:*&rows=20&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.pivot=Size_width,Size_length
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution I was looking for :) It worked perfectly! :D

Answer (score 3):

Solr [pivot faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting) should do what you are asking for. If it does, you may want to be more precise on what specifically fails.